# Image pop-out on mouse hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover

I had an image of a play button on my webpage I'm building with HTML but I have added some code and it has changed the image to a square or it created an image over my play button of a square.

How do I rectify that and get the code to apply to my play button image?

Also I want the image to pop outward when I hover the mouse over it, instead right now it goes inward.

HTML

```
<a class="thumbnail" <IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP: 516px; LEFT:1233px; WIDTH:130px; HEIGHT:130px" SRC="play button.png"</a>
```

JQUERY

```
$('.thumbnail').mouseover(function() {
 $('.thumbnail').removeClass('hover');
 $(this).addClass('hover');
});
```

CSS

```
.thumbnail:hover, .thumbnail.hover {}
.thumbnail:hover span, .thumbnail.hover span {}
```

Comment: Your HTML is not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand what you're looking for, but here's some VALID HTML and a working pop out on hover which you can adjust to your needs:

```
<a class="thumbnail">
    <img src="http://randolph.k12.nc.us/schools/whs/buttons/teal-button-png.png" alt="" />
</a>
```

CSS goes like this (and edit at will):

```
.thumbnail:hover:after{content:'Hello!';background:#fc0; width:300px; height:100px; position: absolute; z-index:2; top:20px; left:30px;

}
.thumbnail:hover span, .thumbnail.hover span {
}
img {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left:0px;
    width:200px;
    height:130px
}
```

and you can see the [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ztmw0pq7/). Your JS isn't needed at all.

As we're at it, please pay attention on the use of the img tag, and don't use spaces in file names.

Comment: that's not the kinda of pop out I want. I want the image itself to pop out a bit or enlarge denoting to the user that its a button and it's clickable

Answer (score 1):

your html is not valid, silly.

```
<a class="thumbnail">
<IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP: 516px; LEFT:1233px; WIDTH:130px; HEIGHT:130px" SRC="play-button.png">
</a>
```

that should fix it

Comment: ok thanks...correction made there and square is removed but its not making my image pop out on mouse hover